# Item enabled on form load even though it's IsEnabled is bound to a presumably false value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, isenabled

I expect LastNumberWeeks NumericUpDown to be disabled on form load but it isn't.  Once I switch the radio selection back and forth it works properly, just not on first load.  Outside of explicitly setting this value in the code behind what can I do (I really don't want to have to use a code behind because of this one case).

```
<RadioButton GroupName="DayRangeGroup" Content="Last number of usable occurences:"  Name="LastUsableOccurancesRadioButton" IsChecked="True" />           
<winControls:NumericUpDown x:Name="LastUsableOccurances" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=LastUsableOccurancesRadioButton, Path=IsChecked}"   />      
<RadioButton GroupName="DayRangeGroup"Content="Last number of weeks:"  Name="LastNumberOfWeeksRadioButton"  />          
<winControls:NumericUpDown x:Name="LastNumberWeeks" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=LastNumberOfWeeksRadioButton, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Comment: PS: I've tried explicitly setting IsChecked="False" in the XAML for the second radio button to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the XAML with a `TextBox` instead of the `winControls:NumericUpDown` and it is working as expected on load, so it's not a problem with the XAML. Try setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged to see if it might help. You can also try using a view model to bind to instead of binding to the element.

Comment: So if it works with a textbox then it's a problem with my custom control, I see.  I'm already doing MVVM so I added some properties to bind to which worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: May as well give you the points, if someone comes along with a real explanation of something we're both missing I'll have to switch it.  Thanks.